# Can't pop starting destination using navigation and jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am using the latest versions of navigation and compose on Android, and i am getting a bug where i can't pop the starting destination of the navigation.
The problem is, if i have 3 destinations (A,B,C) and go from A-> B -> C, i can't pop A from the backstack , but B is popped when i call `popUpTo(B)` `inclusive = true`, causing the back button to go back to A.

My code:

**NavHost**

```
setContent {

        val navController = rememberNavController()

        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "route_to_a"
        ) {

            composable("route_to_a") {
                LoginScreen(navController)
            }

            composable("route_to_b") {
                RegisterScreen(navController)
            }

            composable("route_to_c") {
                HomeScreen(navController = navController)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Navigations**

**- A to B**

```
Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("route_to_b")}) {}
```

**- B to C**

```
Button(onClick = {
    navController.navigate("route_to_c") {
        popUpTo("route_to_b") {
            inclusive = true
        }
    }
}) {}
```

I want to create a flow where neither A and B are on the backstack after getting on C. But for some reason i can't remove A from the backstack...how can i do it?

Comment: You need to `popUpTo("route_to_a") { inclusive = true }` instead. See more info in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavOptionsBuilder?hl=hu#popUpTo(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace,

```
popUpTo("route_to_b") {
    inclusive = true
}
```

with this,

```
popUpTo("route_to_a") {
    inclusive = true
}
```

From [Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-to-composable),

```
// Pop everything up to and including the "home" destination off
// the back stack before navigating to the "friends" destination
navController.navigate("friends") {
    popUpTo("home") { inclusive = true }
}
```